# Can REST chrome extension return attachement

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension

I would like to test the API that I wrote.

My API `@Produces("text/csv")` and return header `content-disposition: attachment; filename = research.csv`

I can see in my REST logging filter the following:

```
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-3
2 < 200
2 < content-disposition: attachment; filename = algopix-research.csv
2 < Content-Type: text/csv
"885909727919","whateve","Apple iPhone 5s 16GB 4G LTE Gold - Sprint"
"885909727919","whateve","Apple iPhone 5s 16GB 4G LTE Gold - Sprint"
```

However in [REST chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) I don't get it as an attachement but as String output:

```
"885909727919","whateve","Apple iPhone 5s 16GB 4G LTE Gold - Sprint"
"885909727919","whateve","Apple iPhone 5s 16GB 4G LTE Gold - Sprint"
```

I do see the following response headers

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
content-disposition: attachment; filename = algopix-research.csv
Content-Type: text/csv 
Content-Length: 143 
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 19:06:08 GMT
```

Is it a bug in my code or REST chrome extension doesn't return attachemnt?

Comment: Are you talking about a public extension available in Chrome Web Store?  If so, please put the link to the extension in CWS.  On the other hand, if you are writing the extension, I assume you are using xmlHTTPRequest, right?

Comment: I refer to the one in Chrome Web Store

Comment: I should ask to the extension's authors: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/support